# PHP URL Generation

Tags: php

I have a set of data being returned to a table using PHP and MySQL and I would like to put a link at the end of this data using elements from the row to build the link with some static elements.

i.e. $urlStart/name-installer-date-email-gno$urlEnd

```
<tr>
                 <th>Installer Ref:</th>
                 <th>Fitter</th>
                 <th>Guarantee</th>
                 <th>Equipment</th>
                 <th>Installed</th>
                 <th>Options</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
                $i=0;
                while ($i < $num) {
                    /* $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"installer"); */
                    $f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"fitter");
                    $f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"guarantee_no");
                    $f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"equipment");
                    $f5=mysql_result($result,$i,"certificate_no");
                    $f6=mysql_result($result,$i,"install_date");
            ?>
            <tbody>         
                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f2; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f3; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f4; ?></td>
                <!-- <td><?php echo $f5; ?></td> -->
                <td><?php echo $f6; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$link = "$urlStart/name-$f6-$email-$f3$urlEnd";
```

Comment: Thats great thanks however it prints out the same link every time I need it to print the relevant link for ear line in the table I am getting the results like this:

Comment: What about `$link = "$urlStart/name-$f6-$email-$f3$urlEnd"`?